# .dwproj cannot be opened because its project type (.dwproj) is not supported by this version of the application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

When i try to open the SSAS project file, visual studio 2015 throw the following exception:

> 'projectfile.dwproj` cannot be opened because its project type (.dwproj) is not supported by this version of the application.
>
> To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project.

*Screenshot*

[image: ssis error on vs2015]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to use Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS).  It's a customized version of Visual Studio for developing this stuff.  You used to get it by installing SQL Server Data Tools.

Answer (score 13):

## Trying to figure out the issue

I think this is an issue of Visual Studio 2015 that require installing an extension:

This issue was cited in the [following link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49805/dwproj-from-vs2015-not-loading-incompatibility-err.html), and the author found the following solution:

> In the Extensions and Updates select "online" and search for "Microsoft Analysis Services Modeling" that toolset will provide the dwproj extensions.

So in Visual Studio:

1. Go to Tools >> Extensions and Updates
2. Select the Online option
3. Search "Microsoft Analysis Services Modeling" or "Microsoft Analysis Server Projects"
4. Install the extension

If you did n't fund the extension you can install it manually from the following link:

- [Microsoft Analysis Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects#review-details)

## Update 1

Also make sure that you installed SQL Server Data Tools:

- [SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx)
- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

## Update 2

If none of the instructions above solved the issue, make sure you have installed the latest update for Visual Studio 2015:

- [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and .NET Core 1.0 Available Now](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/)

Comment: I had to search `Microsoft Analysis Services Projects` instead in Visual Studio extension gallery. I'm using VS 2019.